# in my website error GET http://localhost:8000/storage/img/ 404 (Not Found)

Tags: laravel, get, localhost

I have a project in laravel but I have a problem GET http://localhost:8000/storage/img/ 404 (Not Found) like a picture any one can help me 
the website works fine but shows error in devtools chrom I can't find the problem

[image: mage from my browser]

I have data.blade.html file

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
@php
   $img=$post->images->first();
   $img_name=$img['image'];
@endphp

<a id="brick{{$post->id}}"href="/{{$post->id}}" class="card p-2 m-2 mb-3 shadow">
<div class="" >
  <img class="card-img-top border" src="storage/img/{{$img_name}}" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='storage/img/car.jpg'" alt="Card image cap">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">{{$post->title}}</h5>
    <h6 class="card-text">{{$post->text}}</h6>
    <h4><span class="badge badge-primary">{{number_format($post->price,2)}} Dzd</span></h4>
  </div>
</div>
</a>

@endforeach
```

and hameController

```
public function ok2()
     {
         $posts=Post::select('id','title','text','price','user_id')
        ->latest()
        ->paginate(1);
        $view = view('data',compact('posts'))->render();

        return response()->json(['html'=>$view]);
     }
```

and java script

```
$(function(){
var page=15 ;


    $(window).on("scroll", function() {
                if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {


                    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
                    {
                        page++;
                        loadMoreData(page);
                    }
                }

            });

    function loadMoreData(page){
      $.ajax(
            {
                url: '/ok2?page=' + page,
                type: "get",
                beforeSend: function()
                {
                    $('.ajax-load').show();
                }
            })
            .done(function(data)
            {
                if(data.html == ""){
                    $('.ajax-load').html("No more records found");
                    return;
                }
                $('.ajax-load').hide();

                var box = document.createElement('div');
                box.innerHTML = data.html;
                console.log(box);
                bricklayer.append(box);





            })
            .fail(function(jqXHR, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
            {
                  alert('server not responding...');
            });
    }











});
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

In blade view file, you call `$post->images`
You should make sure that the `images` relationship has been created.

If `images` relationship has been created. You should use [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) to achieve optimal speed.

And you need to make sure any posts has an image.

Finally, check `$img` varible:

```
@if (filled($img))
<img class="card-img-top border" src="storage/img/{{$img_name}}" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='storage/img/car.jpg'" alt="Card image cap">
@endif
```